# Docker image fail due to gcc (cytoolz)

Tags: python, docker

I have a python flask application which I want to deploy on ubuntu server with docker.

So I transferred my whole application folder to ubuntu directory.

Then with root user, I am trying to create a dockerfile in the application folder as below:

```
# Docker file for Support

# Pulling from base Python image

FROM python:3.7

# author of file
LABEL maintainer="Baktaawar"

# Set the working directory of the docker image
WORKDIR /support
COPY . /support


# packages that we need

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install build-essential
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 8888

CMD ["python", "index.py"]
```

The requirements.txt file is the conda env packages list exported via

```
pip freeze> requirments.txt
```

These are the packages in that.

```
thinc==6.10.2
cytoolz==0.8.2
msgpack-numpy==0.4.1
msgpack-python==0.5.6
pathlib==1.0.1
termcolor==1.1.0
ujson==1.35
spacy==2.0.11
dash==0.26.2
dash-core-components==0.30.0rc1
dash-dangerously-set-inner-html==0.0.1
dash-html-components==0.11.0
dash-renderer==0.13.1
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
HTMLParser==0.0.2
matplotlib==2.1.2
matplotlib-venn==0.11.5
numpy==1.15.2
pandas==0.20.3
plotly==3.1.1
wordcloud==1.5.0
```

But when I run this via

```
docker build -t support .
```

It starts installing but at the very end it throws an error for cytoolz and gcc error.

I got the gcc installed via build-essential as shown in my dockerfile. Also using 3.7 instead of python3.6-slim to avoid other gcc issues.

```
      tstate->exc_type = local_type;
               ^~
    cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9126:11: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
         tstate->exc_value = local_value;
               ^~
    cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9127:11: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
         tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
               ^~
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-oprwuva4/cytoolz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-s_ua1t8c/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-oprwuva4/cytoolz/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following:

```
gcc --version
```

If it's not installed add the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

Comment: Adding a little bit of information by editing your answer to explain how this solves the question would be awesome.

Comment: With a python:3.7 base are 3.6 headers a problem?

Comment: It worked. I installed python3-dev with a -y option. My whole docker image is pretty big. I wanted to use python3.6-slim but it was giving error there.